# std::unordered_set of enum, calling find gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

enum Config
{
    NO_NEW_LINE,
    TO_FILE,
    NO_CONSOLE
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_set<Config>> configurations;
    configurations->emplace(Config::NO_NEW_LINE);
    if (configurations->find(Config::NO_NEW_LINE) == configurations->end())
        std::cout << "nothing found " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't have any idea why this code gives segmentation fault.

Here's gdb (things were in namespace SLog)

```
0x00005555555b2a1a in std::_Hashtable<SLog::Config, SLog::Config, std::allocator<SLog::Config>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<SLog::Config>, std::hash<SLog::Config>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true> >::_M_bucket_index (this=0x0, __k=@0x7fffffffdbb4: SLog::NO_NEW_LINE, __c=0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable.h:631
631       { return __hash_code_base::_M_bucket_index(__k, __c, _M_bucket_count); }
```

Comment: Your shared_ptr doesn't manage any instance of `unordered_set`. You need to create it by `new` or make_shared.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Type> name;` is not like `Type name;`, it is like `Type* name = nullptr;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your shared_ ptr manages nothing.
It is equivalent to:

```
std::unordered_set<Config>* configurations;
```

In the old world.

You can easily fix it by:

```
configurations.reset(new std::unordered_set<Config>);
```

Or as @user4581301 suggested:

```
auto configurations = std::make_shared<std::unordered_set<Config>>();
```

Comment: `auto configurations = std::make_shared<std::unordered_set<Config>>();` might be a bit easier to read and wrangle, long term